# c# provide highlighted text to outlook html mail message

Tags: c#, html, outlook, office-interop

I am providing following HTML text to outlook :

```
<span style="background-color:yellow;">test</span>
```

I am providing this with Interop:

```
mailItem.To = ...;
mailItem.Subject = ...;
mailItem.HTMLBody = result.Data.Content;
```

However, in Outlook, I can not remove the the highlight.

[image]

> How to format the HTML so Outlook will recognize it as a 'highlighted' text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your span to:

```
<span style='background:yellow;mso-highlight:yellow'>
```

It looks like Microsoft has some specialized attributes.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the reply!